# What is the P-probability of an unhedged call-arbitrage to lose money at expiration

Tags: black-scholes, risk-neutral-measure, arbitrage, probability, hedge

Assume that the Risk Neutral Price (under the $\mathbb{Q}$-measure) of an European Call Option with expiration date $T$  has a price of $F(S_0,0)$ at time $t=0$ in the single asset Black-Scholes model (without dividens and zero interest rate, $r=0$).

Suppose that we are somehow "skillfull" egnouh to sell this option for $F(S_0,0) + \varepsilon$ at time $t=0$, invest the money into the risk-free asset, and do not hedge our risk. Then **I want to find the probability (under the $\mathbb{P}$-measure) of our "portfolio" denoted by $V$ to expire with a loss**, i.e. $\mathbb{P}(V(T) < 0)$. We clearly have that
$$V(T)=F(S_0,0)+\varepsilon -(S_T-K)^+ \quad, \\ \quad \text{where } (\cdot)^+ \equiv \max( \;\cdot \; , \;0) \text{ is the payoff function for the call-option}.$$

I get the idea of how to perform these calculation but I do now know how to handle to payoff function in the probability. As a starting point I know that the stock price is a GBM with SDE
$$dS_t = \mu S_t dt + \sigma S_t dW_t \quad , \quad S_0 = s.$$
As this is a GBM we know that the solution is given by
$$S_t=S_0e^{\left(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)t+\sigma W_t}.$$

Plugging this into our problem yields
$$\mathbb{P}(V(T)<0) = \mathbb{P}\left(F(S_0,0)+\varepsilon-(S_T-K)^+ <0\right)$$
$$=\mathbb{P}\left(F(S_0,0)+\varepsilon-\left(S_0e^{\left(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)T+\sigma W_T}-K\right)^+ <0\right)$$

I do not kow how to continue from here. However, I would like to argue (i do not know how) that i can look apart from the $+$, then isolate for $W_T$ and use that $W_T = z\cdot\sqrt{T}, \;z\sim N(0,1)$. This would give me an expression similar to something like $N(d_2)$ in the Black-Scholes formula.

Comment: Your suggestion seems fine.  The + can safely be ignored because the inequality cannot be true otherwise.

Comment: Also, I don’t see a factor corresponding to the risk free rate investment you mention.

Comment: @dm63 I might not be following how you see that the + can be ignored as' the inequality cannot be true otherwise'. I see that in the case that $S_T < K$ the set is clearly empty and thus the probability is 0. However, I cannot see how this justify the removal of the + entirely.

Comment: Well you don’t change the answer if you remove a subset of probability zero do you? One of us is missing something !

Comment: I agree with that. In our case is the subset we are removing (cause of 0 probability) is whenever $S_T < K$?